# Can I resolve pointer from CordaRPCOps?

Tags: corda

Consider the following:

```
data class ChildState(
   val name: Party,
        override val linearId : UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier()
) : LinearState
data class ParentState(
        val name : Party,
        val children : LinearPointer<ChildState>,
        override val linearId : UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier()
) : LinearState
```

Can I somehow, as [this Mathew Lyton post](https://medium.com/@matthewlayton/corda-relational-data-pointers-6d4c1b1d41df) seems to suggest, obtain the child state querying just the parent from outside the module using CordaRPCOps? Somehting like this:

```
// rpc.proxy is a NodeRPCConnection containing the CordaRPCOps
val parentStateData = rpc.proxy.vaultQueryBy<ParentState>().states.single().state.data

// perhaps something like this?
parentStateData.children.resolve(rpc.proxy)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default implementation of `StatePointer` in Corda doesn't support resolving a pointer using the `CordaRPCOps`. It can only be resolved using the `ServiceHub` or the `LedgerTransation`. Below are the methods defined in the `StatePointer` class in Corda.

```
/**
 * Resolves a [StatePointer] to a [StateAndRef] via a vault query. This method will either return a [StateAndRef]
 * or return an exception.
 *
 * @param services a [ServiceHub] implementation is required to resolve the pointer.
 */
@DeleteForDJVM
abstract fun resolve(services: ServiceHub): StateAndRef<T>

/**
 * Resolves a [StatePointer] to a [StateAndRef] from inside a [LedgerTransaction]. The intuition here is that all
 * of the pointed-to states will be included in the transaction as reference states.
 *
 * @param ltx the [LedgerTransaction] containing the [pointer] and pointed-to states.
 */
abstract fun resolve(ltx: LedgerTransaction): StateAndRef<T>
```

Neither the `ServiceHub` not the `LedgerTransaction` is accessible in the rpc client, hence in order to resolve the pointer using the `CordaRPCOps`, you will need to write a custom implementation as described in the [blog](https://medium.com/@matthewlayton/corda-relational-data-pointers-6d4c1b1d41df) you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.